# Where in PhpStorm 2020 system/cache directories?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Using PhpStorm 2019 I knew that its internal data is stored under `~/.PhpStorm2019.x` directory.

1. Sometimes it was useful saying when I lack space on my root partition.
   `~/.PhpStorm2019.x/system` was one of directories I deleted at first.
2. Also in case of falling my Kubuntu OS I could copy old `~/.PhpStorm2019.x` into new OS and so I restored my `~/.PhpStorm2019.x` old files of old system.

But are there some system config/cache directories for PhpStorm 2020.1 I did not find.

Can I do similar way I made in 2019 branch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, since 2020.1 it was moved to adhere the platform guidelines. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/tuning-the-ide.html#default-dirs

### The folder with config (IDE-wide settings):

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/tuning-the-ide.html#config-directory

#### - Windows:

```sh
%APPDATA%\JetBrains\<product><version>

# for example:
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PhpStorm2021.1
```

#### - Linux:

```sh
~/.config/JetBrains/<product><version>

# for example:
~/.config/JetBrains/PhpStorm2021.1
```

#### - Mac:

```sh
~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/<product><version>

# for example:
~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PhpStorm2021.1
```

### The system folder (caches/indexes and alike):

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/tuning-the-ide.html#system-directory

Similar paths to the above e.g. `~/.cache/JetBrains/PhpStorm2021.1` for Linux.

---

**P.S.** If you install your IDE using [JetBrains Toolbox App](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) then the path may differ. In such case better check `idea.log` file for the paths used (will be at the start of the session). Use `IDE Main Menu | Help | Show Log in XXX` to locate such file.

Comment: Thanks! 1) is it enogh to copy fully ~/.config/JetBrains/PhpStorm2021.1 to new OS to restore all settings? 2) Has ~/.config/JetBrains/PhpStorm2021.1 any cache directories I can delete safely. Or some other place?

Comment: @PetroGromovo **1)** Works that way for me on Windows for many years. Using standalone installer to install the IDE, not Toolbox App. **2)** Check the first link I gave you. Config folder: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/tuning-the-ide.html#config-directory; System (cache/indexes etc): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/tuning-the-ide.html#system-directory